# Scroll View and Image view - Image will be different at run time

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have a problem which drives me crazy. I want to be able to zoom into a picture and scroll around. So I put a ScrollViewController onto my ViewController. And onto my ScrollViewController an ImageViewController. When I am setting the constraints I am always getting the note, that the Image will be different at run time. You can see where the yellow dotted lines show where the Image is going to be. I cant get the right constraints to get rid of this error so that my picture isnt cut in half. So when I am running the app in the simulator the Picture is always shifted downwards. The weird thing is when I am not using an Navigation Controller I dont have any errors. I dont know whether this is a bug or if I have a mistake in my constraints which I dont see. Is somebody here to help me ? To see the picture Click on "Screenshot xCode"
Thanks

Update: I uploaded a picture how it the view looks on the Scrollview and a picture when the Imageview is being added and it runs in the simulator.
i needed to delete the firs picture due to my reputation. But in the "screenshot2 xcode" shows the same problem

[screenshot 2 xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoLDH.png)

[screenshot 3 simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq5aZ.jpg)

Comment: try deselcting the adjust scroll view insets for your view controller, also see if extend edges option is selected or not in the xcode for the view controller.

Comment: it makes no difference to check or uncheck extended edges. What do you mean by "deselcting the adjust scroll view insets for your view controller". Dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a view as a content view inside scrollview. You need to add following constraint to your contentview

```
- leading
- trailing
- top
- bottom
- width (equal to scorllview)
- height(equal to scorllview)
```

Its so confusing to add width and height constraint even if you add leading,trailing, top and bottom. But this width and height is actually for scrollview content width and content height.

Than add a imageview to contentview. give constraint as follow

```
- leading
- trailing
- top
- bottom
```

Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: when I follow as you told, the frame for the View is also shifting down. I added exactly in the order like you told. It is confusing indeed, because i dont know why it is working without an Navigation Controller. And when the navigationController is embed then the problem occurs

Comment: can you post new screenshot?

Comment: I just found out that the Constraint for the top is always shifting it dow. But without that constraint all other contraints are red

Answer (score 0):

Constraints must be as follow:

Per scroll view: 
Align center x: Superview
Align center y: superview
Equal width: superview
Equal height: superview

Per image View: 
Align center x: superview 
Trailing space: superview 
Leading space: superview 
Bottom space: superview 
Top space: superview 
Height equal: make this the view height

Start all sizing from the top left corner in interface builder